# How to get/import the Scrapy item list from items.py to pipelines.py?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

In my **`items.py`**:

```
class NewAdsItem(Item):
    AdId        = Field()
    DateR       = Field()
    AdURL       = Field()
```

In my **`pipelines.py`**:

```
import sqlite3
from scrapy.conf import settings

con = None
class DbPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupDBCon()
        self.createTables()

    def setupDBCon(self):
        # This is NOT OK!
        # I want to get the items already HERE!
        dbfile = settings.get('SQLITE_FILE')
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    def createTables(self):
        # OR optionally HERE.
        self.createDbTable()

    ...

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.storeInDb(item)
        return item

    def storeInDb(self, item):
        # This is OK, I CAN get the items in here, using: 
        # item.keys() and/or item.values()
        sql = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})".format(self.dbtable, ','.join(item.keys()), ','.join(['?'] * len(item.keys())) )
        ...
```

---

How can I get the item list names (like "AdId" etc) from *items.py*, before `process_item()` (in *pipelines.py*) is executed?

---

I use `scrapy runspider myspider.py` for execution.

I already tried to add "item" and/or "spider" like this `def setupDBCon(self, item)`, but that didn't work, and resulted in:
**`TypeError: setupDBCon() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'`**

---

**UPDATE**: 2018-10-08

**Result (A):**

Partially following the solution from @granitosaurus I found that I can get the item *keys* as a list, by:

1. Adding (a): `from adbot.items import NewAdsItem` to my main spider code.
2. Adding (b): `ikeys = NewAdsItem.fields.keys()` within the Class of above.
3. I could then access the *keys* from my `pipelines.py` via:

```
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.ikeys = list(spider.ikeys)
        print("Keys in pipelines: \t%s" % ",".join(self.ikeys) )
        #self.createDbTable(ikeys)
```

However, there were 2 problems with this method:

1. I was not able to get the *ikeys* list, into the `createDbTable()`. (I kept getting errors about missing arguments here and there.)
2. The *ikeys* list (as retrieved) was re-arranged and **did not keep the order of the items**, as they appear in **items.py**, which partially defeated the purpose. I still don't understand why these are out of order, when all docs says that Python3 should keep the order of dicts and lists etc. While at the same time, when using `process_item()` and getting the items via: `item.keys()` their order remain intact.

**Result (B):**

At the end of the day, it turned out too laborious and complicated to fix (A), so I just imported the relevant `items.py` *Class* into my `pipelines.py`, and use the *item* list as a global variable, like this:

```
def createDbTable(self):
    self.ikeys = NewAdsItem.fields.keys()
    print("Keys in creatDbTable: \t%s" % ",".join(self.ikeys) )
    ...
```

In this case I just decided to accept that the list obtained *seem* to be alphabetically sorted, and worked around the issue by just changing the key names. (Cheating!)

This is disappointing, because the code is ugly and contorted. 
Any better suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy pipelines have 3 connected methods:

> `process_item(self, item, spider)`
>   This method is called for every item pipeline component. 
>   process_item() must either: return a dict with data, return an Item (or any descendant class) object, return a Twisted Deferred or raise DropItem exception. Dropped items are no longer processed by further pipeline components.
>
> `open_spider(self, spider)`
>   This method is called when the spider is opened.
>
> `close_spider(self, spider)`
>   This method is called when the spider is closed.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

So you can only get access to item in `process_item` method.

If you want to get item class however you can attach it to spider class:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    item_cls = MyItem

class MyPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        fields = spider.item_cls.fields
        # fields is a dictionary of key: default value
        self.setup_table(fields)
```

Alternative you can lazy load during `process_item` method itself:

```
class MyPipeline:
    item = None

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if not self.item:
        self.item = item
        self.setup_table(item)
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it the first way, using *open_spider()*. So I have the *MySpider* and *MyPipeline* classes in different files. Why did you put them in the same? (Doesn't seem to be a standard way to do it.) Also what do you mean with: `item_cls = MyItem`? Do you mean (in my case): `NewAdsItem`?

Comment: There is a typo: `item_cls` should probably be `items_cls`. In addition the returned dict create a secondary problem, as the item *names* are not in the original order, but seem to have been put in alphabetical order. Any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: I'm just being generic in my answer, whatever your structure is and whatever your Item is called is not really relevant. Regarding ordering issue you should open up a new issue as it's not related either.